# XRDP Compiling on Ubuntu (Image)

Tags: ubuntu

So I've got the source code for XRDP for Linux and I'm looking for a way to change the image that's there when you connect where it says XRDP on the bottom right corner; does anyone know how to change the default logos by changing images inside the source? There's not much to show as far as code goes it's more of a hit and miss if anyone knows what to edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images appear to be bmp files in the xrdp folder:

http://xrdp.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=xrdp/xrdp;a=tree;f=xrdp;hb=HEAD

You can swap these for different images.

You'll want to keep the licence in mind if you are planning to redistribute:

http://xrdp.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=xrdp/xrdp;a=blob_plain;f=COPYING;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

By the way even after compiling , you can set bmp image file, there is provision in `xrdp.ini` file.

```
;full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=/usr/share/xrdp/xrdp_logo.bmp(default) or /your/path/to/custom-bmp-file
```